# How to print Lightning icon?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, rendering, printpdf

We're having below markup in Lightning component.

```
<lightning:icon aura:id="statusIcon" iconName="action:check" size="xx-small"/>
```

When java-script is controller prints the page with this component, seems like it's omitting this icon.

`window.print();` is used to print the page.

Is there a way I can get this icon on printed output?
Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like only [icon type](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/) - `Doctype` and `Utility` are visible when printed.

Comment: @RahulSharma Thanks, even utility:check did not print when I tried. I used print to PDF to view the output.

Comment: Can you add post some code which is not working as expected?

Comment: Hi @RahulSharma it's the same code with different icon type as you suggested. I tested in firefox.  <lightning:icon aura:id="statusIcon" iconName="utility:check" size="xx-small"/>